# laravel excel import data does not properly working

Tags: laravel

I’m working on laravel excel import. The data can be loaded using 
$data = Excel::load($path)->get(); command. But, when i try to loop through $data object and put it in $insert[], some fields remaining empty.

**my import function look like**

```
public function import(request $request) {

   $path = $request->file('select_file')->getRealPath();

   $data = Excel::load($path)->get();


   if(!empty($data) && $data->count()){

     foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

         $insert[] = [
                  'Item_name'    => $value->Item_name,
                  'Manufacturer' => $value->Manufacturer,
                  'Serial_no'    => $value->Serial_no,
                  'Model_no'     => $value->Model_no,
                  'status'       => $value->status,
                  'Price'        => $value->Price,
                  'photo'        => $value->photo,
                  'user_id'      => $value->user_id,
                  'deletedBy'    => $value->deletedBy,
                  'created_at'   => $value->created_at,
                  'updated_at'  => $value->updated_at,
              ];   

      }


   if(!empty($insert)){

  $insertData = DB::table('inventories')->insert($insert);

   if ($insertData) {
                Session::flash('success', 'Your Data has successfully imported');
              }else {                        
                Session::flash('error', 'Error inserting the data..');
                return redirect()->back();
              }
   } 
 }

   return redirect()->back();

  }
```

when I dd($data); the result looks as

[image]

and the result of dd($insert);  looks as [image]

if any friend can help me that why some fields like Item_name, Manufacturer, and Serial_no remain null, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

solved!
all value->item_names must write in lowercase; I thought that it should match with the database table column names.